# How to raise multiple non-field errors

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

The `clean` method is the place to raise non-field errors:

```
def clean(self):
   cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
   if condition1(cleaned_data['f1'], cleaned_data['f2']):
       raise ValidationError('Condition1 error')

   if condition3(cleaned_data['f3'], cleaned_data['f4']):
       raise ValidationError('Condition2 error')
```

But what if I want to raise both so that the user sees all errors at once instead of having to correct them one by one?

This is possible with field errors passing a dictionary to `ValidationError`, but what about non-field errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Form [`add_error` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) to do this:

```
if condition1(cleaned_data['f1'], cleaned_data['f2']):
   self.add_error(None, ValidationError('Condition1 error'))

if condition3(cleaned_data['f3'], cleaned_data['f4']):
   self.add_error(None, ValidationError('Condition2 error'))
```